# Display array when button in clicked in PHP

Tags: php, array

I have an array as such:

```
Array([0]=>1001 [1]=>1002 [2]=>1003 [3]=>1004)
Array([0]=>2001 [1]=>2002 [2]=>2003)
```

I am trying to display the array in a table like below:

| Location | user |
| --- | --- |
| Office | 4 |
| Canteen | 3 |

The user column is supposed to display the total count in the array. I am able to do that, however I am trying to display the array values when the number is clicked. Please help me solve this issue.

User_model.php

```
function get_user_count($location){
    $this->db->select('user_id');
    $this->db->from('time_location');
    $this->db->where('location', $location);
    $this->db->where('ack', 1);
    $query = $this->db->count_all_results();
```

controller.php

```
$status = $this->User_model->get_user_count($location);
if($status){
     $object_id = array_column($status, 'user_id');
     $this->table->add_row($location, $object_id);
} else{
  $object_id = 0;
  $this->table->add_row($location, $object_id);
}
```

So far I am able to do this to display the total user count in the location. How to make the count value as a link/button where if clicked, it will display the user_id array?

Answer (score 0):

this is the Magento community .

Your code seems to be written in another PHP framework.

I think you are using the CI or Laravel framework, ask your question to the CI/Laravel or https://stackoverflow.com/ community.